# Working with CSV files

Tags: powershell, csv

Suppose I have a table like this in data.csv:

```
time    channel x   y   z
0.001   point 1 1   2   3
0.001   point 2 4   5   6
0.001   point 3 7   8   9
0.001   point 4 10  11  12
0.001   point 5 13  14  15

0.002   point 1 2   3   4
0.002   point 2 5   6   7
0.002   point 3 8   9   10
0.002   point 4 11  12  13
0.002   point 5 14  15  16

0.004   point 1 3   4   5
0.004   point 2 6   7   8
0.004   point 3 9   10  11
0.004   point 4 12  13  14
0.004   point 5 15  16  17
```

How do I make Powershell to write out 3 files (Xdata.csv, Ydata.csv, Zdata.csv), which Xdata.csv should look like this:

```
time    point 1 point 2 point 3 point 4 point 5
0.001   1       4       7       10      13
0.002   2       5       8       11      14
0.004   3       6       9       12      15
```

So far, my code looks like this:

```
# Path to current directory
$path = [System.IO.Path]::GetDirectoryName($myInvocation.MyCommand.Definition)

# csv filename to be imported from
$filename = "data.csv"

$data = Import-Csv "$path\$filename"

# Array of unique values of times
$times = $data | % { $_.time } | Sort-Object | Get-Unique

# Array of unique values of channels
$channels = $data | % { $_.channel } | Sort-Object | Get-Unique
```

But at this point, I am struggling of how to set up an output table just like the one above.

Comment: You could try using the `format-table` command.

Comment: If it is for interactive session (e.g. no need for automation), then excel pivot table is an easy fix :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use `Group-Object` + some logic to generate objects using data from each 'time' snapshot

```
$collections = @{
    x = @()
    y = @()
    z = @()
}


$data | Group time | ForEach-Object {
    $x = New-Object PSObject -Property @{
        time = $_.Name
    }

    $y = New-Object PSObject -Property @{
        time = $_.Name
    }        

    $z = New-Object PSObject -Property @{
        time = $_.Name
    }        

    foreach ($item in $_.Group) {
        if ($item.channel) {
            $x | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name $item.channel -Value $item.x
            $y | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name $item.channel -Value $item.y
            $z | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name $item.channel -Value $item.z
        }
    }

    $collections.x += $x
    $collections.y += $y
    $collections.z += $z

}

foreach ($coordinate in 'x','y','z') {
    $collections.$coordinate | Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation "${coordinate}data.csv"
}
```

This is with assumption that 'data' contains object similar to one I could generate with:

```
New-Object PSObject -Property @{
    time = 0.001
    channel = 'point 1'
    x = 1
    y = 2
    z = 3
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help!  But when I run the script, I got an error that Add-Member cannot bind argument to parameter 'Name' because it is an empty string.  I believe it is because there are empty rows in the source csv.  I executed a command `$data | Group time` and noticed it included empty values coming from empty rows.  Is there a way to make it not include empty rows?

Comment: Error suggests `$item.channel` is empty string.. updated answer to process only when it's not.

Comment: Now the errors doesn't show anymore, but a blank row is still added to the output csv files.

Comment: I just fixed that problem by adding `Where-Object { ( $_.PSObject.Properties | Where-Object { $_.Value } ) } |` just before `Import-Csv $data |`.

Answer (score 0):

More of a pipeline approach (not tested)

```
$axes = @{
x = [ordered]@{}
y = [ordered]@{}
z = [ordered]@{}
}

import-csv data.csv |
 foreach-object {
  if ( $axes.x.containskey($_.time) )
   {
     foreach ($axis in 'x','y','z')
      { $axes.$axis[$_.time].add($_.channel,$_.$axis) } 
   }

  else { 
        foreach ($axis in 'x','y','z')
        { $axes.$axis[$_.time] = [ordered]@{ time = $_.time;$_.channel = $_.$axis } }
       }
 }

 foreach ($axis in 'x','y','z')
  {
   $(foreach ($time in $axes.$axis.values)
   { [PSCustomObject]$time })| 
     export-csv ${$axis}data.csv -NoTypeInformation 
  }
```